# YEOMAN: yo, bower, npm, Grunt & Gulp...OH MY!!!...but really, about these errors during install.

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, bower, yeoman

**Here is the long & short of it.**

I do mostly back-end & middle(Java stack).  Starting to get a little bolder with the front-end.  And I have some questions about errors I saw during install.  Questions & much more, detailed below.

**The Setup**

My machine is Windows 10, 64x.

I DL Node.js about a month ago.  Hardly touched since.

From the Node.js command prompt(Ran as an admin).

BTW, Node.js cmd has its target set to:

*C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\nodejs\nodevars.bat"*

And, location set to:

*C:\Users\ReedW\Desktop*

...pretty sure that doesn't matter a bit.

Started working down the "GETTING STARTED WITH YEOMAN".

Found here:

http://yeoman.io/learning/index.html

Made it to "and then run":

*$ yo webapp*

[image: YEOMAN]

Right after this, he asked me if he could install 2 things...I don't remember what they were...but, of course I said yes.

So after a oppressive amount of text flying down & out of my cmd, we make it to the end.

But I noticed along the way, I saw a few errors in there.  You will see for your self as I have included a large piece of my cmd output, in which all the thrilling details really come to life!

Honestly, the more you can tell me great.  Because I need to learn this stuff.  But even if you can give me some ballpark answers, I'll be very happy.

My questions are:

1) Are these show stoppers or simply to be expected?

2) What can you tell me about them/why are they here?

3) Do I need to fix them/how should I fix them?

```js
:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\
bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Windows\System32\my-yo-project\node_modules\grunt-browser-sync\n
ode_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\no
de_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.1.0

> bufferutil@1.1.0 install C:\Windows\System32\my-yo-project\node_modules\grunt-
browser-sync\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socke
t.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferuti
l
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Windows\System32\my-yo-project\node_modules\grunt-browser-sync\node_modules\b
rowser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\en
gine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config
_node_gyp (node "C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules
\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.4.3, which is not support
ed by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & <
 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:119:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\confi
gure.js:108:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:742:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1183:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.close (net.js:485:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\
bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Windows\System32\my-yo-project\node_modules\grunt-browser-sync\n
ode_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\no
de_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.1.0

> node-sass@3.3.2 install C:\Windows\System32\my-yo-project\node_modules\grunt-s
ass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Binary downloaded and installed at C:\Windows\System32\my-yo-project\node_module
s\grunt-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-14\binding.node
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.1.0

> node-sass@3.3.2 postinstall C:\Windows\System32\my-yo-project\node_modules\gru
nt-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

` C:\Windows\System32\my-yo-project\node_modules\grunt-sass\node_modules\node-sa
ss\vendor\win32-x64-14\binding.node ` exists.
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
jit-grunt@0.9.1 node_modules\jit-grunt

grunt-contrib-clean@0.6.0 node_modules\grunt-contrib-clean
└── rimraf@2.2.8

grunt-concurrent@1.0.1 node_modules\grunt-concurrent
├── async@0.9.2
└── pad-stdio@1.0.0 (lpad@1.0.0)

grunt-newer@1.1.1 node_modules\grunt-newer
├── rimraf@2.2.8
└── async@0.9.0

grunt-filerev@2.3.1 node_modules\grunt-filerev
├── each-async@0.1.3
├── convert-source-map@1.1.1
└── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2
.1.0, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.0)

grunt-contrib-copy@0.8.1 node_modules\grunt-contrib-copy
├── file-sync-cmp@0.1.1
└── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2
.1.0, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.0)

time-grunt@1.2.1 node_modules\time-grunt
├── figures@1.3.5
├── number-is-nan@1.0.0
├── date-time@1.0.0
├── text-table@0.2.0
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2
.1.0, strip-ansi@3.0.0, has-ansi@2.0.0)
└── pretty-ms@1.4.0 (get-stdin@4.0.1, is-finite@1.0.1, parse-ms@1.0.0, plur@1.0.
0, meow@3.3.0)

grunt-contrib-concat@0.5.1 node_modules\grunt-contrib-concat
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0
.2.0, has-ansi@0.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0)
└── source-map@0.3.0 (amdefine@1.0.0)

grunt-contrib-watch@0.6.1 node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch
├── async@0.2.10
├── tiny-lr-fork@0.0.5 (debug@0.7.4, faye-websocket@0.4.4, noptify@0.0.3, qs@0.5
.6)
├── gaze@0.5.1 (globule@0.1.0)
└── lodash@2.4.2

grunt-postcss@0.5.5 node_modules\grunt-postcss
├── diff@1.4.0
├── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2
.1.0, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.0)
├── bluebird@2.10.0
└── postcss@4.1.16 (js-base64@2.1.9, source-map@0.4.4, es6-promise@2.3.0)

grunt-modernizr@0.6.0 node_modules\grunt-modernizr
├── colors@0.6.2
├── promised-io@0.3.5
├── uglify-js@1.3.3
└── request@2.27.0 (forever-agent@0.5.2, oauth-sign@0.3.0, aws-sign@0.3.0, qs@0.
6.6, tunnel-agent@0.3.0, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, cookie-jar@0.3.0, mime@1.2.1
1, node-uuid@1.4.3, form-data@0.1.4, http-signature@0.10.1, hawk@1.0.0)

grunt@0.4.5 node_modules\grunt
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── which@1.0.9
├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
├── getobject@0.1.0
├── colors@0.6.2
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── async@0.1.22
├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── exit@0.1.2
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.7)
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.1, lru-cache@2.7.0)
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.2, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── underscore.string@2.2.1
├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
├── findup-sync@0.1.3 (glob@3.2.11, lodash@2.4.2)
├── grunt-legacy-log@0.1.2 (grunt-legacy-log-utils@0.1.1, underscore.string@2.3.
3, lodash@2.4.2)
└── js-yaml@2.0.5 (argparse@0.1.16, esprima@1.0.4)

grunt-contrib-htmlmin@0.4.0 node_modules\grunt-contrib-htmlmin
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0
.2.0, has-ansi@0.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0)
├── pretty-bytes@1.0.4 (get-stdin@4.0.1, meow@3.3.0)
└── html-minifier@0.7.2 (relateurl@0.2.6, change-case@2.3.0, concat-stream@1.4.1
0, cli@0.6.6, clean-css@3.1.9, uglify-js@2.4.24)

grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.12.3 node_modules\grunt-contrib-cssmin
├── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2
.1.0, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.0)
├── clean-css@3.4.1 (commander@2.8.1, source-map@0.4.4)
└── maxmin@1.1.0 (figures@1.3.5, pretty-bytes@1.0.4, gzip-size@1.0.0)

grunt-contrib-uglify@0.8.1 node_modules\grunt-contrib-uglify
├── uri-path@0.0.2
├── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2
.1.0, strip-ansi@3.0.0, has-ansi@2.0.0)
├── uglify-js@2.4.17 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, async@0.2.10, yargs@1.3.3, sou
rce-map@0.1.34)
├── maxmin@1.1.0 (figures@1.3.5, pretty-bytes@1.0.4, gzip-size@1.0.0)
└── lodash@3.10.1

grunt-usemin@3.1.1 node_modules\grunt-usemin
├── path-exists@1.0.0
├── debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
├── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2
.1.0, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.0)
└── lodash@3.10.1

grunt-wiredep@2.0.0 node_modules\grunt-wiredep
└── wiredep@2.2.2 (propprop@0.3.0, minimist@1.2.0, chalk@0.5.1, through2@0.6.5,
glob@4.5.3, lodash@2.4.2, bower-config@0.5.2)

grunt-svgmin@2.0.1 node_modules\grunt-svgmin
├── log-symbols@1.0.2
├── each-async@1.1.1 (onetime@1.0.0, set-immediate-shim@1.0.1)
├── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2
.1.0, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.0)
├── pretty-bytes@1.0.4 (get-stdin@4.0.1, meow@3.3.0)
└── svgo@0.5.6 (whet.extend@0.9.9, colors@1.1.2, mkdirp@0.5.1, coa@1.0.1, sax@1.
1.2, js-yaml@3.3.1)

autoprefixer-core@5.2.1 node_modules\autoprefixer-core
├── num2fraction@1.2.0
├── browserslist@0.4.0
├── postcss@4.1.16 (js-base64@2.1.9, source-map@0.4.4, es6-promise@2.3.0)
└── caniuse-db@1.0.30000304

grunt-eslint@16.0.0 node_modules\grunt-eslint
├── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2
.1.0, strip-ansi@3.0.0, has-ansi@2.0.0)
└── eslint@0.24.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, object-assign@2.1.1, path-is-abso
lute@1.0.0, xml-escape@1.0.0, user-home@1.1.1, strip-json-comments@1.0.4, estrav
erse-fb@1.3.1, globals@8.8.0, text-table@0.2.0, estraverse@4.1.0, debug@2.2.0, o
ptionator@0.5.0, mkdirp@0.5.1, minimatch@2.0.10, concat-stream@1.5.0, espree@2.2
.4, is-my-json-valid@2.12.2, doctrine@0.6.4, js-yaml@3.4.2, escope@3.2.0, inquir
er@0.8.5)

grunt-babel@5.0.1 node_modules\grunt-babel
└── babel-core@5.8.24 (path-is-absolute@1.0.0, try-resolve@1.0.1, path-exists@1.
0.0, babel-plugin-remove-debugger@1.0.1, babel-plugin-inline-environment-variabl
es@1.0.1, babel-plugin-property-literals@1.0.1, babel-plugin-remove-console@1.0.
1, slash@1.0.0, babel-plugin-undefined-to-void@1.1.6, babel-plugin-eval@1.0.1, b
abel-plugin-member-expression-literals@1.0.1, babel-plugin-react-display-name@1.
0.3, shebang-regex@1.0.0, trim-right@1.0.1, babel-plugin-constant-folding@1.0.1,
 babel-plugin-jscript@1.0.4, to-fast-properties@1.0.1, fs-readdir-recursive@0.1.
2, babel-plugin-dead-code-elimination@1.0.2, babel-plugin-proto-to-assign@1.0.4,
 babel-plugin-runtime@1.0.7, babel-plugin-react-constant-elements@1.0.3, globals
@6.4.1, private@0.1.6, esutils@2.0.2, convert-source-map@1.1.1, home-or-tmp@1.0.
0, js-tokens@1.0.1, line-numbers@0.2.0, debug@2.2.0, babel-plugin-undeclared-var
iables-check@1.0.2, chalk@1.1.1, is-integer@1.0.6, detect-indent@3.0.1, repeatin
g@1.1.3, babylon@5.8.23, resolve@1.1.6, output-file-sync@1.1.1, minimatch@2.0.10
, source-map@0.4.4, bluebird@2.10.0, source-map-support@0.2.10, json5@0.4.0, reg
expu@1.2.0, regenerator@0.8.35, lodash@3.10.1, core-js@1.1.4)

grunt-contrib-imagemin@0.9.4 node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin
├── gulp-rename@1.2.2
├── async@0.9.2
├── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2
.1.0, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.0)
├── pretty-bytes@1.0.4 (get-stdin@4.0.1, meow@3.3.0)
└── imagemin@3.2.0 (get-stdin@4.0.1, path-exists@1.0.0, optional@0.1.3, through2
@0.6.5, meow@3.3.0, buffer-to-vinyl@1.0.1, concat-stream@1.5.0, stream-combiner2
@1.0.2, vinyl-fs@1.0.0, imagemin-svgo@4.1.2, imagemin-gifsicle@4.2.0, imagemin-o
ptipng@4.3.0, imagemin-jpegtran@4.3.0)

grunt-mocha@0.4.13 node_modules\grunt-mocha
├── mocha@1.21.5 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.2, diff@1.0.8, growl@1.8.1, commander
@2.3.0, debug@2.0.0, mkdirp@0.5.0, glob@3.2.3, jade@0.26.3)
├── lodash@3.10.1
└── grunt-lib-phantomjs@0.6.0 (eventemitter2@0.4.14, semver@1.0.14, temporary@0.
0.8, phantomjs@1.9.18)

grunt-browser-sync@2.1.3 node_modules\grunt-browser-sync
└── browser-sync@2.9.3 (longest@1.0.1, async-each-series@0.1.1, emitter-steward@
1.0.0, ucfirst@0.0.1, opn@2.0.1, dev-ip@1.0.1, pad-left@1.0.2, query-string@2.4.
1, browser-sync-client@2.3.1, ua-parser-js@0.7.9, serve-static@1.10.0, connect@3
.4.0, meow@3.3.0, portscanner@1.0.0, immutable@3.7.5, resp-modifier@5.0.2, anyma
tch@1.3.0, foxy@11.1.3, chokidar@1.0.5, serve-index@1.7.2, easy-extender@2.3.1,
eazy-logger@2.1.2, localtunnel@1.7.0, lodash@3.10.1, browser-sync-ui@0.5.16, soc
ket.io@1.3.6)

grunt-sass@1.0.0 node_modules\grunt-sass
├── object-assign@2.1.1
├── each-async@1.1.1 (onetime@1.0.0, set-immediate-shim@1.0.1)
└── node-sass@3.3.2 (get-stdin@4.0.1, async-foreach@0.1.3, chalk@1.1.1, mkdirp@0
.5.1, meow@3.3.0, glob@5.0.14, npmconf@2.1.2, nan@2.0.9, gaze@0.5.1, request@2.6
1.0, sass-graph@2.0.1, pangyp@2.3.2)
bower not-cached    git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.git#~3.3.5
bower resolve       git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.git#~3.3.5
bower not-cached    git://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#~2.8.3
bower resolve       git://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#~2.8.3
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github
.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.git", exit code of #128 fatal: failed to stat '.': No s
uch file or directory

Additional error details:
fatal: failed to stat '.': No such file or directory
bower not-cached    git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.git#~3.3.5
bower resolve       git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.git#~3.3.5
bower not-cached    git://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#~2.8.3
bower resolve       git://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#~2.8.3
bower not-cached    git://github.com/chaijs/chai.git#*
bower resolve       git://github.com/chaijs/chai.git#*
bower not-cached    git://github.com/mochajs/mocha.git#*
bower resolve       git://github.com/mochajs/mocha.git#*
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github
.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git", exit code of #128 fatal: failed to stat '.': No s
uch file or directory

Additional error details:
fatal: failed to stat '.': No such file or directory
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Error: Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages.
    at C:\Users\ReedW\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-webapp\node_mod
ules\wiredep\wiredep.js:30:56
    at findBowerDirectory (C:\Users\ReedW\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gener
ator-webapp\node_modules\wiredep\wiredep.js:108:27)
    at wiredep (C:\Users\ReedW\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-webapp
\node_modules\wiredep\wiredep.js:37:43)
    at module.exports.generators.Base.extend.end (C:\Users\ReedW\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\generator-webapp\app\index.js:314:5)
    at C:\Users\ReedW\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-webapp\node_mod
ules\yeoman-generator\lib\base.js:429:16
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)

C:\Windows\System32\my-yo-project>
```

I have a few pics of the same thing if that will help?  At least the pics have color.  Thanks a lot of your help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you don't have python installed. Install python 2.7 and run the command:

```
npm config set python C:\Python27\python.exe
```

References: https://www.robertkehoe.com/2015/03/fix-node-gyp-rebuild-error-on-windows/